# I can not to see the main page of the eureka server which start running on the tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I try to run my eureka server registry on the my local tomcat and i can not to see the main page of the eureka server by path http://localhost:8761.
In the tomcat`s logs everything is ok, no errors or other warnings.

I am using tomcat 9.0.56, java - 11

My POM.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ua.ukrposhta</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-registry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>service-registry</name>
    <description>Container for registry micro services</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>Server-Registry</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>scripts/webapp</webappDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <propertiesEncoding>ISO-8859-1</propertiesEncoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>local</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

my application.properties is :

```
server.port=8761
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

# убрать сообщение EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN ...
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=true
eureka.server.renewal-percent-threshold=0.33

# Когда сервер eureka запускается, он пытается получить всю информацию реестра с одноранговых узлов eureka.
# Эта операция повторяется 5 раз для каждого узла
eureka.server.number-of-replication-retries=5

#id приложения (указывать всегда в МС приложениях), по этому id будет искаться сервер. Он должен быть уникальным
spring.application.name=server-registry

#т.к. это не клиент, то убираем лишние настройки
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-regisrty=false

# url, куда абудет происходить регистрация микросервисов
eureka.client.service-url.defualtZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka

# отключение лишних логово
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF

# формат логов
#logging.pattern.console=%C{1.} [%-5level] %d{HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n

# ===============================
#Profiles
# ===============================
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
spring.profiles.default=local
```

and my main class is :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServiceRegistryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

If i try to run my eureka server in the IDEA , then i get OK. Everything is runnning and i can to see the main page like :

[image]

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It is strange, but in my case my eureka server was present by path : http://localhost:8080/Server-Registry and setting in application.properties as server.port was not use with the value 8761.
I could not change anything.